# How can I get gpg to sign a git commit

Tags: git, key, commit, gnupg

I last used git about a decade ago.  Apparently a lot has changed. (Surprise!!!)
BTW: Everything I need to do is on the Xubuntu flavor of Linux.

I made a change to a GitHub project and want to commit it locally so that I can push it up to GitHub.  But

```
git commit -a
```

fails with a message about gpg not signing the commit.  I never had to do that before.  So I asked about it here a month ago and got fragments of answers which I tried to stitch together with documentation (that was not specific to Linux let alone Ubuntu).

I probably made things worse.

What I noticed in passing was that there was a GPG key on my system, created in December 2021 (last year).  I was not aware of doing that and think it unlikely I was aware at the time.  But gpg wanted a passphrase, and I have no record of a passphrase.  So I deleted the key.

I created another key, but GPG seems to be ignoring it, at least for git commits, and does not sign the commit, so the commit fails, as it did originally.

Please, I need step-by step instructions, a real HowTo, because all this stuff is unfamiliar to me, and I know less than you probably expect.  If I have to go looking for answers, I'll probably find something that won't actually work for me -- that seems to be my usual fate.

How do I get git and gpg working again on a local Xubuntu, with no known connection to key servers anywhere else?

Comment: distro shouldn't be relevant for git configuration.   git really hasn't changed that significantly in 10 years either.  And yes, I am going to link you instructions. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key You need to check your git config, it's almost certainly pointed at your old gpg key which you deleted.  For what it's worth ,signing git commits with a gpg key is optional.

Comment: @erik258 that was a big help.  I opted out of signing for now, and can move forward.

Comment: Do you still want to sign commits or are you okay with disabling the signing key?

Answer (score 0):

You can either unset the currently configured signing key or set it to your new one.

Unset old key:

```
git config --global --unset user.signingkey
```

or set new key id:

```
git config --global user.signingkey $idofyoursigningkey
```